# Is Italy a real location in the Ace Combat series?

Tags: ace-combat-7-skies-unknown, ace-combat-series

I found this image of a meme which references a voice line in the game that mentions an "Italian Bistro".  If Italy doesn't exist, how come Long Caster knows what "Italian" is?

[image]

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Italy doesn't exist in Strangereal I thought. Is Italy a real place in the Game series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [trivia section](https://acecombat.fandom.com/wiki/Strangereal#Trivia) of the Strangereal game wiki page states:

> In Ace Combat 7: Skies Unknown, an "Italian bistro" is mentioned by AWACS Long Caster. Note that the word "Italian" does not appear in the original Japanese voice line, meaning it was an addition by the English localization team.

More information about this can also be seen on the "[Fleet Destruction](https://acecombat.fandom.com/wiki/Fleet_Destruction#Trivia)" campaign mission game wiki page:

> The kanji for "Italian" does not appear in the original Japanese version of Ace Combat 7, meaning it was an addition by the English localization team.

So likely this is some mistake in the translations between the Japanese and English versions of the game.